# I can't reach socket.io on serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I recently started working with socket.io and i started getting the hang of it. But overnight something broke and i can't figure out why.
When i call socket.id (in the socket.on) i get undefined. but in other socket.on functions it works fine.

Could anyone explain why this stopped working all the sudden? below is my code.

This is my App.js:

```
socket.on('selectedcard', function(data){
    // if(localStorage.getItem("legstapel" != null)){
    //   var legstapel = localStorage.getItem("legstapel");
    // }
    // else{
    //   var legstapel = [];
    // }
    var legstapel = GAME_LIST[1].legstapel;
    //console.log(PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].hand[data.card]);
    console.log("SOCKET: ", socket.id); //this returns undefined
    console.log("SOCKET: ", SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].id); //and therefor this line throws an undefined error
    var infonext = dealnodeal(GAME_LIST[1].topstapel, PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].hand[data.card]);
    if(infonext[2] == true){
      socket.emit('Boerchoice');
    }
    if(infonext[0] == true && infonext[1] == true){
      currentturn = nextplayer(currentturn);
    }
    else if (infonext[0] == true && infonext[1] == false) {
      goAgain();
    }
    else{
      socket.emit('wrong');
    }

    if(infonext[0] == true){
      legstapel.push(PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].hand[data.card]);         //this is where i need socket.id to work.
      console.log(legstapel)
      GAME_LIST[1].topstapel = PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].hand[data.card];
      GAME_LIST[1].legstapel = legstapel;
    };
    console.log("topstackchange     " + GAME_LIST[1].topstapel);
    //for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
      var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
      socket.emit("topstackchange", {
        topstapel: GAME_LIST[1].topstapel
      });
    //};
  });
```

This is client side:

```
  PickCard = function(Cname){
    var turn = localStorage.getItem('turn')
    console.log(turn);
    if(turn == '1'){
      console.log("card selected : " + Cname);
      socket.emit('selectedcard', {
        card: Cname
      });
    }
    else{
      console.log("Het is niet jouw beurt!");
    }
  };
```

EDIT:
Here is the simplified code:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
  var player = Player(socket.id);
  SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
  PLAYER_LIST[socket.id] = player;


  socket.on('selectedcard', function(data){
    console.log(socket.id); //this is undefined
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think the problem is you are using not the `socket` variable after connection you're using the `socket` module.

```
io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    //this socket refers to the local socket variable which has ID
    socket.on('someEvent', function () {
        //socket.id will be available here.
    })
})
```

refer: [Socket.IO docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-id)

Edit: As the OP is having problems using this piece of code I am attaching a POC for reference.

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('selectedcard', function (data) {
        console.log(socket.id); // this is working
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

client.js (using node for fast prototyping)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.emit('selectedcard', {hey:'yaya'});
```

Result:

```
$ node server.js
U9GFjoTEzOsv0hmoAAAA
{ hey: 'yaya' }
```

Comment: Thanks. So how can i get the id inside socket.on?

Comment: Now you can. the socket.id will be available in the event callback

Comment: i changed io.sockets.on('connection' to what you have but nothing changed

Comment: `io.on` is short of `io.sockets.on`, also `connection` and `connect` events are same (aliases).

Comment: you're event handler is INSIDE the `io.on` connect right? can you post the full code, but simplified in your question?

Comment: Yes it is. i just updated the question. my code is at the bottom.

Comment: I have added a POC, check it out. it's working as expected.

Comment: my gosh thanks for all the help but i'm really not getting it lmao. so i basicly copied your code into mine but obviously require() is not a thing on client side. so now what. really appreciate all your help

Comment: Okay i ended up working around my problem by defining variable "id" at the top of io.on and using that instead of socket.id. it works now lol. thanks for all the help!

Comment: lol np. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client check it for the `require` replacement

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code it is not clear whether the client and server did a successful handshake - they are probably not. You get a socket instance on the server side on successful connection with whom you can get the socket.id e.g. see Aritra's answer

Comment: They did do a succesfull handshake. Or at least i think they did. I think this because this piece of code is executed after server and client have communicated several times before.